# How to speed up index based assignment?

Tags: r, optimization, indexing

I have a problem where the idea is to find unique elements of an extremely large matrix, apply some function (in this example, it is a sine function, but it can be an arbitrary function, even a trained neural net) to each unique element, and then replace it back in the original matrix.

I have the following R code snippet:

```
nrows <- 28000
ncols <- 3000

x <- matrix(round(runif(nrows*ncols, 1, 5), 5), nrow=nrows, ncol=ncols)

u <- unique(as.vector(x))
uindex <- seq(from=1, to=length(u), by=1)
ut <- sin(u)

for (hh in uindex) {
  x[x == u[hh]] <- ut[hh]
}
```

In the above, code-snippet, the portion

```
for (hh in uindex) {
  x[x == u[hh]] <- ut[hh]
}
```

takes forever to finish for the matrix dimension of order 1e4x1e3. How can I optimize the for loop?

Please note that this is just a minimal working example for Stackoverflow only. Hence, please refrain from telling me that I can do x = sin(x). My point is the `for` loop.

Comment: My initial suggestion would be to avoid the `for` loop entirely.  Is this an option?

Comment: Is the idea here to save time on `sin(x)` operation through applying it to the unique values of `x` only?

Comment: @Limey , I know that for loop is expensive, that's why I am here. What could be the alternative? What should I replace `for` loop with?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment regarding avoiding the `for` loop entirely...

As OP knows, using loops in R is generally slow and if there's an alternative, it's likely to be faster.  One answer that avoids the for loop has already been provided.  Here is another, with benchmarking.

To start, turn the OP's code into a function.

```
withForLoop <- function(nrows=28000, ncols=3000) {
  x <- matrix(round(runif(nrows*ncols, 1, 5), 5), nrow=nrows, ncol=ncols)
  u <- unique(as.vector(x))
  uindex <- seq(from=1, to=length(u), by=1)
  ut <- sin(u)
  for (hh in uindex) {
    x[x == u[hh]] <- ut[hh]
  }
}
```

and benchmark it

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(withForLoop, times=100)

Unit: nanoseconds
        expr min lq  mean median uq  max neval
 withForLoop  47 49 83.46     49 55 3226   100
```

So we are trying to beat a median time of 49 nanoseconds.  (You could, of course, pick any other summary statistic as your target metric.)

Now rewrite the code using the tidyverse.  OP's code starts with a matrix, converts it to a vector and then manipulates the vector.  It's not clear if the matrix needs to be recovered.  Assume it does, so provide the means to recover it, but - for consistency with OP's code - don't do the recovery.

```
library(tidyverse)

withTidyverse <- function(nrows=28000, ncols=3000) {
  x <- tibble() %>% 
         expand(
           Row=1:nrows,
           Col=1:ncols
         ) %>% 
         mutate(
           Random=round(runif(nrow(.), 1, 5), 5),
           Sin=sin(Random)
         )
}

microbenchmark(withTidyverse, times=100)

Unit: nanoseconds
           expr min lq  mean median uq max neval
 withTidyverse1  41 42 52.21   42.5 43 964   100
```

So that's reduced the median execution time to 42.5 nanoseconds on my machine.  That's a saving of just over 13%.

Because `sin` is a relatively quick function I've not bothered to search for unique values and replace each unique value in a batch.  I've just taken a blunderbuss approach and recalculated each value in the vector as it arises.  Here's a way of taking the more sophisticated, "replace unique values in batches" approach:

```
withTidyverse2 <- function(nrows=28000, ncols=3000) {
  x <- tibble() %>% 
    expand(
      Row=1:nrows,
      Col=1:ncols
    ) %>% 
    mutate(
      Random=round(runif(nrow(.), 1, 5), 5)
    )
  y <- x %>% 
         distinct(Random) %>% 
         mutate(Sin=sin(Random))
  x <- x %>% 
         left_join(y, by="Random")
}

microbenchmark(withTidyverse2, times=100)

Unit: nanoseconds
           expr min lq  mean median uq  max neval
 withTidyverse2  44 45 82.31   45.5 51 2543   100
```

So, in this specific case, the overhead of extracting the unique values and updating in batches is not worthwhile, although it is still quicker than the `for` loop.  OP will have to investigate their actual use case.

There are, of course, lots of other ways to address the actual problem.  Which one is optimal is impossible to say based on the information provided.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort to produce this remarkable answer. I will incorporate this into my use-cases, test it and provide feedback here.

Comment: Does `microbenchmark` test that `withForLoop` is a function and then evaluate `withForLoop()`? (I do not usually use that package.) Beause if not, you are not really evaluating the function's body?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` based solution:

```r
nrows <- 28000
ncols <- 3000

x <- round(runif(nrows*ncols, 1, 5), 5)
u <- unique(as.vector(x))

uindex = seq(from = 1, to = length(u),  by = 1)


dt.x <- data.table(x)
dt.u <- data.table(u)
dt.u[, ut := sin(u)]
dt.res <- merge(dt.x, dt.u, by.x = "x", by.y = "u", all.x = TRUE)
ut <- dt.res[, ut]

output <- matrix(ut, nrow=nrows, ncol=ncols)
```

Main idea here, is to work with the vectors and tables. I think you can convert to the matrix at the very end.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  What is `dt.u[, ut := sin(u)]` doing? I am not aware of this syntax.

Comment: And I am not sure you did there. In this problem basically, the idea is to find unique elements of an extremely large matrix, apply some function (in the above example, it is a sine function) to each unique element, and then replace it back in the original matrix. It didn't work out with your method. It would be helpful, had I understood what you were doing with `dt.u[, ut := sin(u)]`.

Comment: this just creates a new column in the data.table

Comment: If you are not familiar with data.table, I recommend https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/data-table-cheat-sheet

Comment: I have also added `all.x = TRUE` in the merge, to make it a left join, though in the sample data it should not make a difference, only if you real data has NAs

Answer (score 0):

You could use `match`:

```r
    nrows <- 28000
    ncols <- 3000
    
    x <- matrix(round(runif(nrows*ncols, 1, 5), 5), nrow=nrows, ncol=ncols)
    u <- unique(as.vector(x))
    ut <- sin(u)
    
    i <- match(x, u)
    ut[i]
```